# Javascript SQL Attack: Someone inserted a script into MySQL that prevented me from deleting their row. What am I at risk for here?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin, code-injection

A user inserted a 
    `<script src=...> </script>`

Code in my database, and using phpmyadmin, I was not able to delete the row. The page just kept refreshing everytime I tried, and the row was still there.

Fortunately, I was using an incognito window in chrome, and found that by refreshing the session and deleting the row directly (without viewing it first), I was able to remove it. I changed my database password and cleaned my code to prevent html input -- what else is at risk here?

Is phpMyadmin that sensitive to injected javascript code?

**To Clarify**: Phpmyadmin was the only website I visited in this incognito window, so it could not have come from a different website

Comment: Are you even serious? I do all kinds of XSS attacks against my dbs and phpmyadmin never interpreted a single line of HTML. Doing `htmlspecialchars()` on all fields is expected behavior and not even much older versions of phpmyadmin would fail that I believe.

Comment: Hi Fabricio, In the incognito window, I did not access any other page. I went straight to phpmyadmin. So how is this possible then?

Comment: The problem isn't phpMyAdmin - it's your web application, which isn't correctly escaping HTML when it renders user input from the database.

Comment: You probably had a connection problem or some session issue that caused the page to refresh. Are you sure it was interpreted as a script? Wasn't it just text on your screen?

Comment: It was text on my screen. But that was the only row I could not edit or delete. I was only able to do so if the session have never accessed that row.

Comment: Check that your version of phpmyadmin is as up-to-date as possible. A web search reveals XSS in old versions.

Comment: Thanks Adder -- that answers my question. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions( < 4.0 ) of phpMyAdmin are vulnerable to SQL injections and cross site scripting. I suggest you update to the latest version if you don't have it.

You can get the latest version here: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/‎

Also take a look how to prevent XSS(Cross site scripting)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-secxss/ or you could just google it if you find the link is hard to understand. Hope it helps <3

Answer (score 1):

No phpmyadmin has no risk (if you have put a password and use an other login as root , of course ! ). All risks come from your other webpages where data could be inserted into your database.

[Go to this section on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: This contradicts the description of the problem.

Comment: In the incognito window, this was the only page I visited. How is that possible?

Comment: Nothing to do with the viewing mode in your browser. I Think it's the data in your database which are corrupted.

Comment: So data in my database can be corrupted so that I can not delete the row? How is that possible?

Comment: No, you can delete the row corrupted but I mean you might have a hole in your front page which allow to add bad codes in your database.

Answer (score 1):

When outputting user-submitted data, you should always ensure that it has been properly sanitized. Otherwise, you're leaving yourself open to the possibility of [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. Sanitizing output is easy with the function [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($userSubmittedData, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

Also, I'd advise against stripping tags etc on input as it may result in a loss of data integrity. Simply make sure that you use [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars) whenever you're **outputting** user-submitted data.

Comment: Hi Wayne, again -- the issue was strictly with phpmyadmin. I had already cleansed outputted data and have now also cleansed inputted data more rigorously.

Comment: Be careful about cleansing input too rigorously as you may inadvertently strip out important data.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your version of phpmyadmin is as up-to-date as possible. A web search reveals XSS in old versions.

I found these headlines:

PhpMyAdmin version 3.5.7 vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting

Full Disclosure: phpMyAdmin 3.3.5 / 2.11.10 <= Cross Site Scripting

You can browse phpmyadmin security fix history at:
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/security/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accepting input in raw manner.Please use htmlspecialchars and encoding while inserting into database.

Comment: This contradicts the description of the problem. Escaping does not help if the < sign is valid content for the input.

Comment: use htmlspecialchars to suppress this type of attack

Comment: No, not when inserting into a database, but on output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution : this is called XSS attacks :

use  strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string()) when ever you insert data into mysql database through php .

Comment: SQL injection has nothing to do with XSS. And do not use `strip_tags`, but `htmlspecialchars` on **output**.

Comment: i know ,you have to use strip_tags to avoid xss attacks !!

Comment: Use PDO rather than the deprecated mysql_ functions which were deprecated precisely because they encourage security blunders.

Comment: yes ,PDO is good ,use Filters also to make it bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that someone is able to inject malicious code. You need to ensure that all user input (including query strings in the url) is sanitised correctly (on the server rather than just via javascript) before being added to the database. For any field allowing text you should search for suspicious strings such as `<script` and so on. Even better (as long as it doesn't break the functionality of your site) is to have a whitelist of allowed characters so that it is impossible to enter malicious code. e.g just allow alphanumeric characters and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you! As mentioned, I have prevented future HTML inputs.